# Uses for Pork gelatin?

Tags: pork, gelatin

I bought a whole pig with a friend. Along with the meat, we each received several bags of skin with ~1/2" of fat.

I figured I'd render the fat for tamales, pies or perhaps make some soap. When a sample batch cooled, I found that another by-product of this is gelatin.

I'll end up with over a gallon (maybe two) of pretty stiff gelatin. Definitely stiffer than any chicken stock I've made. I'd rather not toss it.

What can I do with it? There are no bones involved. Stock?

Comment: Hello mmccoo. We have very tight "culinary uses" guidelines. An ingredient as common as pork gelatin doesn't fall under them, sorry.

Comment: It's unfortunate that many stackexchange questions get caught by the hold/closed mafia. If you don't like the question then vote it down.

Answer (score 1):

One option is Pozole Rojo (Mexican Red Pork and Hominy Stew) - Here's a recipe from Rick Bayless: [Pazole Rojo](http://www.culinate.com/books/collections/all_books/Mexico+One+Plate+at+a+Time/pozole_pork_and_hominy_stew) You won't need the trotters, and shanks are optional since you already have the gelatin. If you want you can just use shoulder. Good stuff!

It would also be great for bean or split-pea soup.